# read.csv importing two columns instead of one

Tags: r, csv

I'm trying to import a csv file into a vector. There are 100 entries in this csv file, and this is what the file looks like:

[image]

My code reads as follows:

```
> choice_vector <- read.csv("choices.csv", header = FALSE, fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM")

> choice_vector
```

And yet, when I try to display said vector, it shows up as:

[image]

It is somehow creating a second column which I cannot figure out why it is doing so.  In addition, trying to write to a new csv file actually writes the contents of that second column to that as well.

Comment: Try to remove any white space in the excel and save or just copy only the first column and save as new file and read

Comment: @akrun What do you mean white space? All the entries are in individually cells, and it would seem hard to go through each entry individually.

Comment: Ok, you could copy only the first column and save it as a different file. May be there is some character in the second column that created. the additional column

Comment: try using the colClasses parameter as shown here:https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16796/reading-only-two-out-of-three-columns-with-read-csv . I don't know why are you getting two columns though.

Comment: @akrun turns out that did the trick, but what if this happens again, with a larger subset of data? Is it possible in R to filter out any whitespace detected?

Comment: @yuritsuki. It is not clear what is causing this issue.  may be you can specify `read.csv(("choices.csv", header = FALSE, fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM", strip.white = TRUE)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second column was "habilitated" in excel.

**Option1**: Manually delete the column in excel.
**Option2**: Delete all columns with all NA

```
choice_vector2 <- choice_vector[,colSums(is.na(choice_vector))<nrow(choice_vector)]
```

In case of being interested in reading the first column only:

```
choice_vector <- read.csv("choices.csv", header = FALSE, fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM")[,1]
```

Good luck!

Comment: So is the [,1] indicating the range in which you want columns to be read? ie, 0 to 1? How would indicate reading specific rows in that case?

Comment: @yuritsuki as follows: [row,column]

Answer (score 3):

Short answer:
You have an issue with your data file, but

`choice_vector <- read.csv("choices.csv", header = FALSE, fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM")$V1`

should create the vector that you're expecting.

Long answer:

The `read.csv` function returns a data frame and you need to address a particular column within the data frame with the `$` operator in order to extract that column as a vector. As for why you have an unexpected column of NAs, your CSV probably codes for two columns. When you read a CSV with R, a comma indicates a data field to its right. If you look at your CSV with a text editor, I'm guessing it'll look like this:

```
A,
B,
D,
A,
A,
F,
```

The absence of anything (other than another comma or a line break) to the right of a comma is interpreted as NA.

Answer (score 2):

If we are using `fread` from `data.table`, there is a `select` option to select only the columns of interest

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread("choices.csv", select = 1)
```

---

Other than that, it is not clear about why the issue happens.  Could be some strange white space.  If that is the case, specify `strip.white = TRUE` (by default it is `FALSE`)

```
read.csv(("choices.csv", header = FALSE, 
     fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM", strip.white = TRUE)
```

Or as we commented, copy the columns of interest into a new file, save it and then read with `read.csv`